# Rows omitted on import from CSV to mysql due to encoding

Tags: mysql, csv, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I got the next CSV file:

```
1 Café 
2 Chair
3 Hallå
4 Dog
```

(And ~10000 more rows of words of all latin characters)

I'm trying to get this data into a mysql table using phpMyAdmin.

But even though I've set both the database and table encoding to utf8_bin, what I get after import is:

```
2 Chair
4 Dog
```

Meaning all non-english characters makes the whole row disappear from the table.

I've also tried utf8_general_ci, which I think doesn't suppose to work, and indeed, it didn't work.

Which encoding should I use? Or, is there something I can do with the file before import that will allow me to import it correctly?

Comment: You need to make sure the connection is encoded properly. Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Not really, my database and tables already encoded as utf8, as suggested in the top answer. I'm just seem to miss something more specific

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is embarrassing, but it might be helpful for somebody in the future.

While I **did** set both the database and table encoding to `utf8_bin`, I've ignored the fact that the **column** encoding was set to `utf8_general_ci`. Fixing the column encoding made the import successful.

Use utf8_bin on both database, table, **and column**.